# Create new object in JSP to foreign key

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I`ve got two object and tabels [in SQL]: Employee and Invoice.
One employee can issue multiple invoices. Invoice has a foreign key to Employee.

I would like to create view (in JSP),where when adding an invoice, it will be selected existing employee [from SQL] form drop-down list. But I don`t know how I can "make" object Employee in JSP. I do this:

Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
 /.../

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
private List<Invoice> invoice;
```

Invoice:

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "invoice")
    public class Invoice {
           /.../
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_employee")
    private Employee employee;
```

InvoiceController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/invoice-add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addInvoice(Model model) {

        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("invoice", new Invoice());
        model.addAttribute("employeeList", employeeList);

        return "invoice-add";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/invoice-add/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveInvoice(@ModelAttribute Invoice invoice, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "invoice-add";
        }
        invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
        return "redirect:/invoice";
    }
```

invoice-add.jsp:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="invoice" action="${invoiceAddURL}" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
/.../
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <form:select path="employee">
         <c:forEach var="employee" items="${employeeList}">
         <form:option value="${employee.id}" label="${employee.name}" />
         </c:forEach>
         </form:select>

      </div>
</form:form>
```

... but it doesn`t work [error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'invoice' available as request attribute". But when I removed code related with "foreign key" it works]. Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: can you able to post what error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, the error is: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'invoice' available as request attribute". But when I removed code related with "foreign key" it works :-/